# Tor browser not working in college (which uses proxy server)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I used the Vidalia bundle but am unable to access internet with the Tor browser.  Please help me configure the settings (I don't exactly know how the Tor browser or Vidalia work, so the more information the better).
Thanks.

Comment: Vidalia is not maintained anymore. Please use the Tor Browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your tor browser to use the proxy of your university to access the internet. Therefore, open the `Tor Network Settings` and select the second field: "This computer needs to use a local proxy to access the Internet".
However: This might compromise your anonymity in the first place, e. g. if you have to login with university credentials. Please inform yourself about risks, problems and pitfalls, this might producde.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on bridges mode in browser settings. It was designed for this specific scenario.

[Here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges) is the link that includes all the requested walkthroughs, screenshots, and other *stuff* you wanted for the answer from The Tor Project itself.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this, or where to find this setting? Screenshots are often helpful.

Comment: @AndrewLott its explained at length on torproject.org. I'll add a link and be done with it.

Comment: Please give a basic breakdown if you can. Link-only answers aren't appreciated without some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After you launch the Tor Browser click on Open Settings. You'll be asked to Connect or Configure. Click "Configure", select "Yes" then "Next" then "Yes" or "No" on if you need to use a local proxy (you probably won't need to). After that just hit "Connect". All the bridge information will be stored in your torrc.